# Using pymunk gravity with pyglet

Tags: python, game-physics, pyglet, pymunk

This code displays the image `assassin1.png` on a black screen standing still at position (50, 80).

The goal is to induce the pymunk gravity on that image so that it falls down. I followed the [pymunk tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/pymunk/wiki/SlideAndPinJointsExample) which is written using pygame and tried to adapt that. I don't know why my code isn't applying gravity to the my image. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong and what I should change to make it work properly?

```
import pyglet
import pymunk

class PymunkSpace(object):
    def assassin_space(self, space):
        self.space = space
        self.mass = 91
        self.radius = 14
        self.inertia = pymunk.moment_for_circle(self.mass, 0, self.radius) 
        self.body = pymunk.Body(self.mass, self.inertia) 
        self.body.position = 50, 80 
        self.shape = pymunk.Circle(self.body, self.radius) 
        self.space.add(self.body, self.shape) 
        return self.shape 

class Assassin(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, batch, img, x, y):
        pyglet.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, img, x , y )

class Game(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        pyglet.window.Window.__init__(self, width = 315, height = 220)
        self.batch_draw = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.a_space = PymunkSpace().assassin_space(space)
        self.player1 = Assassin(batch = self.batch_draw, img = pyglet.image.load("assassin1.png"), x = self.a_space.body.position.x ,y = self.a_space.body.position.y )

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.batch_draw.draw()
        self.player1.draw()
        space.step(1/50.0) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    space = pymunk.Space() 
    space.gravity = (0.0, -900.) 
    window = Game()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you set the location of your `Sprite` once:

```
self.player1 = Assassin(batch = self.batch_draw, img = pyglet.image.load("assassin1.png"), x = self.a_space.body.position.x ,y = self.a_space.body.position.y )

class Assassin(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, batch, img, x, y):
      pyglet.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, img, x , y )
```

but this location never gets updated.

Another problem is that in the pygame example, `space.step(1/50.0)` is called every iteration of the main loop, while your's only gets called when the window is drawn.

So, first, you should ensure `space.step` gets called every frame. Do so by using a `clock`:

```
class Game(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        pyglet.clock.schedule(self.update)

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.batch_draw.draw()
        self.player1.draw()

    def update(self, dt):
        space.step(dt)
```

The next step is ensuring the location of the sprite is keeped in sync with the pyglet object.

Change your Assassin class:

```
class Assassin(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, batch, img, space):
        self.space = space
        pyglet.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, img, self.space.body.position.x , self.space.body.position.y)

    def update(self):
        self.x = self.space.body.position.x
        self.y = self.space.body.position.y
```

Create your Assassin instance like this:

```
class Game(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        pyglet.window.Window.__init__(self, width = 315, height = 220)
        self.batch_draw = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.a_space = PymunkSpace().assassin_space(space)
        self.player1 = Assassin(batch = self.batch_draw, img = pyglet.image.load("assassin1.png"), space = self.a_space)
        pyglet.clock.schedule(self.update)
```

and call `self.player1.update()` in your new `update` method:

```
class Game(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def on_draw(self):
        ...

    def update(self, dt):
        self.player1.update()
        space.step(dt)
```

(And you should probably get rid of some unneeded instance members, but that's another topic)

Comment: Note: You still want to have a constant dt sent into the space.step method, because the simulation will behave more stable and quicker with a fixed time step.

Comment: @viblo Yes, documentation says so, but I have never found this to be an issue.

Comment: Nice explanation, thank you! About your the comment of those unneeded instance members: I assume you are talking about the fact that I put the code of `assassin_space` under a `PymunkSpace` class instead of just in a function? In this case it's certainly unneeded, but wouldn't it be good to use a class to encapsulate all `assassin_space`-like functions for other characters(with a different size e.g.) I'd implement in the game? I would also like to implement collision as well later.